# javascript-made array not being sent to controller as an array?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a view `events/new.html.erb which contains:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'id_array[]', [], id: 'parti_ids'  %>

<%= f.submit "Create Meeting", class: "btn-submit" %>
```

So that, on submit, id_array[] is sent to my `events_controller#create` action as an array. **The problem I am having is that if, for example, I want `id_array = [3,4,5]`, it is passed and picked up at the controller as `["3,4,5"]` instead of `["3","4","5"]`.**

Here is the code in my `application.js` where this is created:

```
var idList = [];

$(document).on('click', "#check-button", function(){

   ....

    $("#check-list li input").each(function(){ //for each listed colleague...
        if( $(this).is(":checked")){ //if check-box is ticked

            idList.push($(this).val()); //add id to idList

        }
    });

    $('#parti_ids').val(idList); //sets idList array to be value of parti_ids hidden_tag_field in view

});
```

I have a feeling it's something to do with the line `$('#parti_ids').val(idList);` , as this is the only place where parti_ids is actually set. But I don't know what's wrong with setting the array value like this, or why it's making things like ["3,4"] instead of ["3","4"].

To show you how I'm using it in my controller, here is a snippet:

```
participants = params[:id_array]
participants.each do |id|
   puts(id) #THIS PUTS THE ENTIRE VALUE OF PARTICIPANTS INSTEAD OF EACH ID
end
```

Comment: Why don't you use the checkbox form helper with the multiple option set to true rather than creating the array client side?

Comment: @Rubysmith I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: [Sending array parameters](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box#1001-Sending-array-parameters)

Comment: @Rubysmith Because the array still has opportunity to be changed elsewhere, I want it to be submitted once it has been calculated. Can you suggest how I can re-write the line where I set the value of #parti_ids?

Comment: The problem is not with the JavaScript instead it is with the hidden_field_tag and how Rails handles params. I guess you might have to generate a hidden field for each of your check-boxes then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'id_array[]', [], id: 'parti_ids'  %>
```

and add this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_array" id="parti_ids" />
```

Then split it.

```
  participants = params[:id_array]
  participants.split(',').each do |id|
    puts(id) #THIS PUTS EACH ID
  end
```

Comment: Doing this has caused the id_array to be passed to the controller as a String "3,4,5" instead of an array, and therefore it's not letting me do participants.each

Comment: Ok, this has made no difference to what I was getting to my controller before. It's still receiving ["3,4,5"] instead of ["3","4","5"]

Comment: The above answer is the simplest workaround for now.